# How to Get Duplicate Contact list iOS and merge or delete Contact?

Tags: objective-c, merge, duplicates, contacts, addressbook

I Want to Delete Duplicate or Merge duplicate Contact Can anyOne Provide me Sample Code for it !!!!!
I want to get the List of Duplicate Contact in tableview and merge them or delete them

Comment: How to fetch contact list ? Through ABAddressBook ?

Comment: i fetched the complete contact list but know i want to get duplicate contact and merge them...!!                                                                             allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

Comment: Than what issue you face by using this allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: i m getting all contacts no issue but now i want sync all the contact and find duplicate contact and merge them and delete another contact....

Comment: @user3182143 thank you brother  let me try it.... if it works for me and can you tell me how to merge this contact with the existing contacts

Comment: My code works perfectly brother.I deleted the duplicate contact as you ask.

Comment: I did what you ask in your question " I Want to Delete Duplicate ".

Comment: thank you brother@user3182143 but its not deleting form the address book contact is available in contact

Comment: can duplicate contact merge with each other  and can you tell me how to compare phone number and remove duplicates

Comment: Not addressbook contact.now it is contact.We don't have concept addressbook in iOS 9 onwards.

Comment: but still in the contact list of my iPhone all the contact are shown including  all duplicate contact  here i want to merge the duplicate contact and delete one off the duplicate contacts.

Comment: @MiteshVaru Have you done it? Because I also want to do same but couldn't do it. If you have done it successfully please help me here!!

Answer (score 5):

I created sample project for you.I got the solution.it works perfectly.

> Addressbook framework is deprecated from iOS 9.So we need to use Contact framework.

**We must import Contact framework**

> Next in plist If you want to access contacts,you have to get
>   authorization permission so you need to add **Privacy - Contacts Usage
>   Description**
>
> Key is Privacy - Contacts Usage Description
>   Type  is string
>   Value is contact  (whatever you want add here as string)

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Contacts/Contacts.h> 

@interface ViewController :  UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblViewContact;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arrData;
    NSMutableArray *arraySearchContactData;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tblViewContact;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [self getContact];
   [tblViewContact registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
 }

 //Get Contact and Authorization Access

-(void)getContact
{
    // Request authorization to Contacts
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted == YES)
    {
      //keys with fetching properties
      NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
      NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
      NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
      NSError *error;
      NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
      if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
      } else {
        NSString *phone;
        NSString *fullName;
        NSString *firstName;
        NSString *lastName;
        UIImage *profileImage;
        NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *arrContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts)
        {
            // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
            firstName = contact.givenName;
            lastName = contact.familyName;
            if (lastName == nil) {
                fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
            }else if (firstName == nil){
                fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
            }
            else{
                fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
            }
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
            if (image != nil) {
                profileImage = image;
            }else{
                profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
            }
            for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers)
            {
                phone = [label.value stringValue];
                if ([phone length] > 0) {
                    [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                }
            }
            NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: fullName,@"fullName",profileImage,@"userImage",phone,@"PhoneNumbers", nil];
            [arrContacts addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[personDict objectForKey:@"fullName"]]];
        }
        //Removing Duplicate Contacts from array
        NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:arrContacts];
        NSArray *arrayWithoutDuplicates = [orderedSet array];
        arrData = [arrayWithoutDuplicates mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"The contacts are - %@",arrData);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tblViewContact reloadData];
        });
       }
     }
  }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 #pragma mark - UITableView Data Source Methods

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
  return 1;
 }

  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return  arrData.count;
 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static  NSString *strCell = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
   if(cell==nil)
   {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
   }
   cell.textLabel.text = arrData[indexPath.row];
   return cell;
 }
```

The Printed results For Contacts

```
The contacts are - (
 "John Appleseed",
 "Kate Bell",
 "Anna Haro",
 "Daniel Higgins",
 "David Taylor",
 "Hank Zakroff"
)
```

Screenshot below

**When first you run the app**

[image]

**Now it shows contacts in table view**

[image]